# Python dataframe 40GB using pandas, calculating statistics without using for loops

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have quite a big DataFrame holding 40GB of data. Suppose I have three columns: 
ID, Speed, Speed limit. There are many repeating ID's. This data is for every second. 
At the end of my calculation, I want to have in a new DataFrame, for each ID, the total amount of kilometers driven and the number of km driven where they overspeeded.

I know how to do this using a loop, but I know that iterating over rows is an issue given it is very slow and that I have approximately 120 million rows. 
What pandas tool can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For the overspeed duration, you can simply use `time_overspeed = (df['speed'] > df['speed_limit']).sum()`. As each row is one second, the result is given in seconds.

For the distance calculation, we have `distance = speed * duration`. Once again, each row is one second, then : `distance = df['speed'].sum() / 3600` (assuming the speed is in km/h and distance in km).

Comment: In this way, I am not getting the solution for each ID though, but just as an aggregate for all the ID's. What I want is, for each ID in the data frame the amount of kilometer that he oversped.